# Temporally store array in Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

So initially I had created a global (I know xd), array where I stored around 600 ~25 chars strings. The array for sure wont get bigger than that. So my question is how to store temporally such an array in Mysql.

I would have used VARCHAR(255) and store it as a string but due to the size I cant. I also though of JSON type, but, at least for me, didn't seem good. Now what am thinking of doing now is;

Since I know that each element in the array will be unique, create a table with 1 column, store them there in many rows, and when done delete the table.

Is that a good/efficient approach or perhaps am missing something out

edit: I forgot to add that the reason i have to store the array, is cause I will need it for a few days and so I cant afford to lose the data in case of a script fail, therefore storing.

Comment: If you are looking for storage to replace a global var, which doesn't persist beyond the current call on the server, why put it into a table at all? If instead, you want to store something that will be available the next time the script is run, then storing in a table might make sense, although with something that small you could just store it in $_SESSION.

Comment: Indeed I forgot to add, that I will need for like a few days, so I cant afford to lose it in case the script fails, thats why I decided to store it in a table.

Comment: You would need more than just the one column in a table, unless it should be universal, ie. visible to all users. One thing you should consider, is to better define what you are trying to do. IOW, how is the data read/written, who can "see" it, etc.

Comment: I only need to know if that id is in the array, so only one column to store it, and then just select and check if the id exists so one table with one column and new row for each id (or at least thats what am thinking)

Comment: I have the impression that this is some quick internal utility. If so, you could possibly just serialize the array as JSON and store it in a file.

Comment: Hmm actually perhaps thats the best, when I thought it at first I immediately crossed it out due to data stability but since in this case thats not really an issue (the data will get deleted in two days), I'll go with that. Thank you both for your help